# How to solve memory limit issue in shared host

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony-1.4, php-5.3

i am getting memory limit error while loading some of the pages of my website.

My issue is, i don't have rights to modify memory_limit in php.ini so is there any other way to override this settings ?

I am getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 122880 bytes) in /xx/xx/xx/plugins/otbcCompanyPlugin/lib/model/om/BaseOtbcCompanyCompanyPeer.php on line 1567
```

i tried:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
echo ini_get('memory_limit');exit; // prints 90M
```

And i tried following in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 512m
</IfModule>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_php.c>
php_value memory_limit 512m
</IfModule>
```

but didn't work.

you can check [phpinfo().](http://norwood.prolix.ro/phpinfo.php)

so is there anything missed by me ?

Comment: First of all, are you sure, you _really_ want to allocate that much memory?

Comment: Typically, changing the memory limit on shared hosts isn't possible. It would be counter-productive to the idea of shared hosting. What do you need this much space for anyway? 512 MB sounds like an insane amount of RAM. Imagine 10 people calling your page at the same time.

Comment: Why do you need that much memory? Is it a specific function/database query causing the issue? Can you optimise it?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange yes its database operations that causing this issue.

Comment: what is the database query?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange there's so many queries it fires i can't tell you here.

Comment: I doubt the quota limit cause your problem. In shared hosts, the resources you can use is limited by administrator, and your settings can not beyond the limit. The usage of ini_set() is right and if on your own server, you can see it works.

Comment: @hardik I can bet you fetch all the data at the same time. Your option is to read one row from resource, process it, release data and read the next one.

Comment: @PLB your right but its old messy code of clients so it will take me days to re factor that. its already working in my local by changing memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. But it's pretty easy:

cPanel > section Software/Services > Select PHP Version menu.

Click on Switch to PHP extensions and there you will see the option for raising the php memory limit as memory_limit.

In some hosts, you can configure the custom php.ini file from here too.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to add your owen php.ini file in wich you specify :

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

to do so :

1. create a php.ini file in your root folder
2. add memory_limit = 512M
3. create .htaccess file and add this line :

`SetEnv PHPRC /home/username/folder/php.ini`

this will load your custom instructions in your php.ini

to make sure just run the

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```